# block access to area/controller's methods but allow inherited controller to run methods, asp .net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I am trying to find out how to block a whole area/controller from being accessed by typing url website.com/area1/basecontroller/method1 (this area also contains the views that will be displayed) , while still being able to inherit said controller and use the method from original controller like so website.com/area2/extendedbasecontroller/method1.

There would not be a method1 in the extendedbasecontroller, it would just perform method1 from the basecontroller

Is it possible or could it be achieved in a different way?

Comment: would it be possible to write a filter which runs before action is executed, checking what area the initilization comes from and if it came from area1 it would stop it from executing ?

Answer (score 1):

A different way is what you want here -- extract a class that does `method1` and then reference the class in both controllers. MVC controllers really shouldn't ever call each other in general.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good way to do or not, but it looks like this accomplishes what I am trying to do:

```
public class BlockActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute,IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {    
        var area = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();

        if(area == "area1")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
        }

        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }            
}
```

I can access the methods in `basecontroller` in area1 by inheriting it to an `extendedbasecontroller` in area2 and using it via that one, but I can't directly use `basecontroller` in area1.